# awk: print only lines that come after specific guard line pattern

Tags: command-line, awk

Consider this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
|dms,wew,qwqw|
|m|head1|
|3,4,6|
|3e,2,23|
|m|head2|
|xw,12,2123|
|23,d,213|
|23,22q,2skl|
|m|head1|
|dljs,wqpw,2;a|
|dllw,w1p,1q;a|
EOL
```

Every once in a while, there will be a 
guard pattern: a line that starts with:

```
|m|
```

(yes, the first line of the file need not 
be a guard pattern)
Now I only want to print those lines 
for which the last guard pattern was:

```
|m|head1|
```

and ignore all other lines. 
In other worst, I would like the output to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > desired_result_file.txt <<EOL
|m|head1|
|3,4,6|
|3e,2,23|
|m|head1|
|dljs,wqpw,2;a|
|dllw,w1p,1q;a|
EOL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex-oriented

```
$ awk '/^\|m\|/ {/\|head1\|/ ? p=1 : p=0} p' example_file.txt 
|m|head1|
|3,4,6|
|3e,2,23|
|m|head1|
|dljs,wqpw,2;a|
|dllw,w1p,1q;a|
```

or field-oriented

```
$ awk -F'|' '$2 == "m" {$3 == "head1" ? p=1 : p=0} p' example_file.txt 
|m|head1|
|3,4,6|
|3e,2,23|
|m|head1|
|dljs,wqpw,2;a|
|dllw,w1p,1q;a|
```

---

`p` is effectively a print flag.

Awk programs consist of `pattern {action}` pairs, in which `action` is executed on a record if `pattern` evaluates true (non-zero). You can omit `pattern` - in which case `{action}` is evaluated for every record - or omit `{action}` in which case awk applies the *default pattern*, which is to print the record: the latter is what's happening here.

Comment: How does the variable p work to control printing? I see how it is set, but where is that explained in the awk manual, etc.?

Comment: @Joe I have added some explanation of the `p`